# Copying an Image using PyOpenCL

Tags: opencl, python-imaging-library, pyopencl

I've been having some trouble making a copy of an image using PyOpenCL. I wanted to try copying as I really want to do other processing, but im not able to understand this basic task of accessing every pixel. Please help me catch the error to make sure it works.

Here is the program

```
import pyopencl as cl
import numpy
import Image
import sys

img = Image.open(sys.argv[1])
img_arr = numpy.asarray(img).astype(numpy.uint8)
dim = img_arr.shape

host_arr = img_arr.reshape(-1)

ctx = cl.create_some_context()
queue = cl.CommandQueue(ctx)
mf = cl.mem_flags
a_buf = cl.Buffer(ctx, mf.READ_ONLY | mf.COPY_HOST_PTR, hostbuf=host_arr)
dest_buf = cl.Buffer(ctx, mf.WRITE_ONLY, host_arr.nbytes)

kernel_code = """
    __kernel void copyImage(__global const uint8 *a, __global uint8 *c)
    {
        int rowid = get_global_id(0);
        int colid = get_global_id(1);

        int ncols = %d;
        int npix = %d; //number of pixels, 3 for RGB 4 for RGBA

        int index = rowid * ncols * npix + colid * npix;
        c[index + 0] = a[index + 0];
        c[index + 1] = a[index + 1];
        c[index + 2] = a[index + 2];
    }
    """ % (dim[1], dim[2])

prg = cl.Program(ctx, kernel_code).build()

prg.copyImage(queue, (dim[0], dim[1]) , None, a_buf, dest_buf)

result = numpy.empty_like(host_arr)
cl.enqueue_copy(queue, result, dest_buf)

result_reshaped = result.reshape(dim)
img2 = Image.fromarray(result_reshaped, "RGB")
img2.save("new_image_gpu.bmp")
```

The image I gave as input was
[image]

However, the output from the program was
[image]

I'm not able to make sense of why those black lines appear.
Please help me solve this bug.

Thank You

OK ! so I've found a solution. I changed all uint8 to int, and in the numpy array i removed the "astype(numpy.uint8)". I dont know why, I just tried this and it worked. An explanation as to why would be helpful. Also, does this mean this will take much more memory now ?
It works, but now I think it takes much more memory. Any workaround using the uint8 will be helpful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a mismatch between the datatypes your are using in Python and OpenCL. In numpy, a `uint8` is an 8-bit unsigned integer (which I presume is what you were after). In OpenCL, a `uint8` is an 8-element vector of 32-bit unsigned integers. The correct datatype for an 8-bit unsigned integer in OpenCL is just `uchar`. So, your `astype(numpy.uint8)` is fine, but it should be accompanied by arrays of `__global const uchar*` in your OpenCL kernel.

If you are dealing with images, I would also recommend looking into OpenCL's dedicated image types, which can take advantage of the native support for handling images available in some hardware.

Comment: Thank you, making the uchar change right now. I tried using the dedicated image type, and tried out [link](http://code.google.com/p/opencl-book-samples/source/browse/trunk/src/Chapter_20/?r=17#Chapter_20%2FPyImageFilter2D) but it was giving me some issues. So decided to use arrays instead.

Comment: since I have more space now , I've decided to send more images in to reduce the memory copy between GPU and CPU. However, I feel that is facing similar problems. All I did was add a `int imgid = get_global_id(0); and index starts with imgid * nrows * ncols * npix` shouldnt that be enough ?

Comment: That sounds roughly right, assuming you are creating the same memory layout when you load the images in Python. Unless the images are very small, I wouldn't expect there to be a huge performance improvement by packing images in this way (in fact, the best approach would probably be to pipeline the process and transfer image `n+1` whilst processing image `n`).

Comment: not really sure how to pipeline it cause `prg.copyImage(queue, (dim[0], dim[1]) , None, a_buf, dest_buf)` is one statement, and only after that i.e. kernel finishes execution does it proceed to the next part which is saving images and then loading the next. Also, isn't transferring 6 MB img1, then 6 MB img2 ..etc back and forth an overhead on copying ? 120 MB of 20 images at one go and then copying back was what I thought of doing. Its doing that in 1 second. The problem now is Image.save takes more time.

Comment: how can I pipeline this, I mean, I tried searching but no direct results. Post a link to an existing similar approach ? And for the sake of argument, isnt 120MB transfer to buffer at a time faster than transfering each 6 MB image processing, and going along ?

Comment: You can overlap memory transfers with computation by using out-of-order command queues or multiple command queues with some OpenCL implementations. Whether or not this will benefit you depends on the ratio of computation time to memory transfer time. If the former is much larger, than you can hide all memory transfer time by pipelining these operations. If not, then you probably wouldn't see any benefit.